# C# Reading multiple elements with same name using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

Is there any better way doing this?
I have to get both property values.
XML always has only these 2 properties.

My xml:

```
<Template name="filename.txt">
  <Property name="recordSeparator">\r\n</Property>
  <Property name="fieldCount">16</Property>
</Template>
```

Linq:

```
            var property = from template in xml.Descendants("Template")
                       select new
                                  {
                                      recordDelim = template.Elements("Property").Where(prop => prop.Attribute("name").Value == "recordSeparator")
                                                    .Select(f => new { f.Value }),
                                      fieldCount = template.Elements("Property").Where(prop => prop.Attribute("name").Value == "fieldCount")
                                                    .Select(f => new { f.Value })
                                  };
```

Comment: Please clarify your question to explain what you're trying to do. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Are you expecting multiple delimiters or fieldCount properties in a single template? Because, Select() returns IEnumerable<T>, in your case IEnumerable<String>. That means that both recordDelim and fieldCount will be of type IEnumerable<String>. Is that what you need in your anonymous object?

Comment: @kornelijepetak, xml is always same and has only these 2 properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Better way" depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve - performance, simplicity, etc.?

I guess I would create a class that contains what you are trying to get with anonymous classes.

```
public class Item {
    public String Separator { get; set; }
    public int FieldCount { get; set; }
}
```

and then I would modify the LINQ to:

```
var templates = from template in xml.Descendants("Template")
                let children = template.Elements("Property")
                select new Item() {
                    Separator = children.First(tag=>tag.Attribute("name").Value == "recordSeparator").Value,
                    FieldCount = Int32.Parse(children.First(tag=>tag.Attribute("name").Value == "fieldCount").Value)
                };

List<Item> items = templates.ToList();
```

Note that this will cause `NullReference` exception in case your Template tag does not contain two Property tags, each with specified attributes.

Also it will throw an exception in parsing the integer from a FieldCount if it's not a number.

**Idea:**

If the xml generated is your own, and you can change it's format, why not do something like:

```
<Template>
  <Name>filename.txt</Name>
  <RecordSeparator>\r\n</RecordSeparator>
  <FieldCount>16</FieldCount>
</Template>
```

It's easier to read and to parse, and it's a little bit shorter.

In the end, I think this is how I would do it:

Having this class:

```
public class Item 
{
   public String FileName { get; set; }
   public String Separator { get; set; }
   public int FieldCount { get; set; }
}
```

and this private method:

```
private Item GetItemFromTemplate(XElement node) 
{
    return new Item() {
        FileName = node.Element("Name").Value,
        Separator = node.Element("RecordSeparator").Value,
        FieldCount = Int32.Parse(node.Element("FieldCount").Value)
    }; 
}
```

I could do in code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myfile.txt");

List<Item> items = (from template in doc.Elements("Template")
                   select GetItemFromTemplate(template)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think i am going to change the structure of the xml because it really is easier to read and parse.

Comment: you might want to consider the edit I've made. To simplify the LINQ query.

Comment: Well, you put quite some effort to the answer :). Although concurring answer +1.

Comment: @hs2d. My asnwers are never perfect. :) I always find a way to improve my solutions :) I'm glad you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little more efficient:

```
var properties =
    from template in xml.Descendants("Template")
    let propertyNodes = template.Elements("Property")
        .Select(arg => new { Name = arg.Attribute("name").Value, Value = arg.Value })
    select
        new
        {
            recordDelim = propertyNodes.Single(arg => arg.Name == "recordSeparator").Value,
            fieldCount = propertyNodes.Single(arg => arg.Name == "fieldCount").Value
        };
```

If you have always one `Template` node:

```
var propertyNodes = xml.XPathSelectElements("/Template/Property")
    .Select(arg => new { Name = arg.Attribute("name").Value, arg.Value })
    .ToList();

var properties =
    new
    {
        recordDelim = propertyNodes.Single(arg => arg.Name == "recordSeparator").Value,
        fieldCount = propertyNodes.Single(arg => arg.Name == "fieldCount").Value
    };
```

Comment: This, of course works, but I wouldn't force anonymous objects, unless you need this info (delimiter, count) only within the method you are doing the LINQ query. Otherwise, I think it would be smart (and maybe even neccessary) to go with the custom created class.

Comment: @kornelijepetak - 100% agree.